# Why does dplyr's mutate() change the time format?

Tags: r, dplyr, readr

I use `readr` to read in data which consists a date column in time format. I can read it in correctly using the `col_types` option of `readr`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(readr)

sample <- "time,id
2015-03-05 02:28:11,1674
2015-03-03 13:10:59,36749
2015-03-05 07:55:48,NA
2015-03-05 06:13:19,NA
"

mydf <- read_csv(sample, col_types="Ti")
mydf
                 time    id
1 2015-03-05 02:28:11  1674
2 2015-03-03 13:10:59 36749
3 2015-03-05 07:55:48    NA
4 2015-03-05 06:13:19    NA
```

This is nice. However, if I want to manipulate this column with `dplyr`, the time column loses its format.

```r
mydf %>% mutate(time = ifelse(is.na(id), NA, time))
        time    id
1 1425522491  1674
2 1425388259 36749
3         NA    NA
4         NA    NA
```

Why is this happening?

I know I can work around this problem by transforming it to character before, but it would be more convenient without transforming back and forth.

```r
mydf %>% mutate(time = as.character(time)) %>% 
    mutate(time = ifelse(is.na(id), NA, time))
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's actually `ifelse()` that is causing this issue, not `dplyr::mutate()`.  An example of the problem of attribute stripping is shown in `help(ifelse)` -

> ```
> ## ifelse() strips attributes
> ## This is important when working with Dates and factors
> x <- seq(as.Date("2000-02-29"), as.Date("2004-10-04"), by = "1 month")
> ## has many "yyyy-mm-29", but a few "yyyy-03-01" in the non-leap years
> y <- ifelse(as.POSIXlt(x)$mday == 29, x, NA)
> head(y) # not what you expected ... ==> need restore the class attribute:
> class(y) <- class(x)
> ```

So there you have it.  It's a bit of extra work if you want to use `ifelse()`. Here are two possible methods that will get you to your desired result without `ifelse()`. The first is really simple and uses `is.na<-`.

```
## mark 'time' as NA if 'id' is NA
is.na(mydf$time) <- is.na(mydf$id)

## resulting in
mydf
#                  time    id
# 1 2015-03-05 02:28:11  1674
# 2 2015-03-03 13:10:59 36749
# 3                <NA>    NA
# 4                <NA>    NA
```

If you don't wish to choose that route, and want to continue with the `dplyr` method, you can use `replace()` instead of `ifelse()`.

```
mydf %>% mutate(time = replace(time, is.na(id), NA))
#                  time    id
# 1 2015-03-05 02:28:11  1674
# 2 2015-03-03 13:10:59 36749
# 3                <NA>    NA
# 4                <NA>    NA
```

**Data:**

```
mydf <- structure(list(time = structure(c(1425551291, 1425417059, 1425570948, 
1425564799), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), id = c(1674L, 
36749L, NA, NA)), .Names = c("time", "id"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Answer (score 4):

There is another version of `if_else` by [@hadley](https://github.com/hadley) in `dplyr`. It correctly manage time variables. Look at [this github issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2582) as well.