# ifelse on data frame column to replace with date time column values if matched

Tags: r, dataframe, posixct

I need help. I am trying to copy the `date_time` column values into new column based on matching values of `txt_col` column and those that are not matched mark as `NA`. Here is my code:

```
df$new_col <- ifelse(df$txt_col == "apple", df$date_time, NA)
```

However, I get numbers in the new column, instead of date-time :

```
   new_col
1477962000
1451755980
1451755980
1451755980
```

When looking at the `str(df)`, the column `date_time` is `POSIXct`.  I tried to convert `as.numeric` and `POSIXct`, it didn't work. If you have more elegant ways to do what I am trying to achieve, it would be much appreciated if you share. Thank you.

Comment: They are the numeric equivalent of the datetime - the number of seconds since 1970-01-01. Wrap the whole thing in an `as.POSIXct()` and you should be fine.

Comment: Don't forget to include a time zone when you wrap it again, processing gets very interesting when the tz changes mid-stream :-)

Comment: `as.POSIXct(1477962000, origin = "1970-01-01 00:00:00")` works for me.

Comment: @r2evans - `as.POSIXct(1477962000, origin = "1970-01-01")` for short

Comment: I've occasionally gone beyond "explicit", thanks.

Comment: @r2evans and TheLateMail - Thank you! :) It does work when I separately wrap with POSIXct ()  on already newly  generated column. But when I wrap it in the original ifelse operation, it still puts the numbers.

Comment: One of the frustrations of `ifelse` is that it strips attributes, including class, which is where the numbers come from—they're how POSIXct is stored. You either need to reassign the class as suggested above, or find another approach that doesn't strip it in the first place.

Comment: @alistaire thank you for your input.

Comment: [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32336773/why-dplyrs-mutate-changes-time-format/32337025#32337025) why.

Comment: @epi99 Thank you! This worked! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Package `dplyr` as a stricter function `if_else` that verifies the classes of both the true and false components. Explicitly providing the class for the NA value makes this more "type safe"

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(txt_col = c("apple", "apple", "orange"),
                 date_time = as.POSIXct(c("2017-01-01", "2017-01-02", "2017-01-03")))

# use dplyr::if_else instead, and provide explicit class
df$new_col <- if_else(df$txt_col == "apple", df$date_time, as.POSIXct(NA))

df
#   txt_col  date_time    new_col
# 1   apple 2017-01-01 2017-01-01
# 2   apple 2017-01-02 2017-01-02
# 3  orange 2017-01-03       <NA>
```